# RelativeLayout alignParentRight become messy after click

Tags: android, click, android-relativelayout

I've been trying to create a layout where I can put a text on the left side of the parent and an ImageView at the right side of the parent in Android. I use RelativeLayout to achieve this, here is the layout file

```
         <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/prop_displ_tbl_descr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="7dp">
                <!-- Description -->
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/prop_displ_rel_descr"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Deskripsi"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/prop_displ_img_collaps_descr"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/prop_displ_img_collaps_descr"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_arrowdown" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/prop_displ_tblrow_descr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/prop_displ_txtdescription"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

The layout is correct at the first display. The problem is because I implement an onTouchListener for the RelativeLayout to make the prop_displ_tblrow_descr TableRow visibility to GONE, sometimes the text disappear and the ImageView will be displayed on the left.

Here is the code:

```
   relDescr.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mDescrIsExpanded = !mDescrIsExpanded;
                setCollapsibleDescr();

                // update ui
                relDescr.invalidate();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

private void setCollapsibleDescr() {
    if(mTblRowDescr != null) {
        if(mDescrIsExpanded) {
            // view is expanded
            mTblRowDescr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mImgDescr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_arrowup);
        } else {
            // view is collapsed
            mTblRowDescr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImgDescr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_arrowdown);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the correct layout (at first display after calling the fragment):
[image: correct layout at first display]

This is the incorrect layout (after click some times):
[image: incorrecy layout after click some times]

It doesn't happen every time but it is quite often and it only happen in my real device and not in the emulator. I use Xiaomi 4i Android Lollipop.

Which part is wrong? How to show a view on the right side of the parent without using relative layout?

Thanks

Comment: Try switching the TextView and ImageView: put first the ImageView and then the TextView

Comment: Have you tried using LinearLayout?

Comment: Hi, how to use LinearLayout to achieve a view to be on the right side of the parent?